# Can the equilbrium constant ever be exactly 1?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

According to my book,

> In the real world [...] it is unlikely that any reaction would have exactly equal concentrations of products and reactants at equilibrium.

This was mentioned in context to the fact that it was an ideal situation for $K_\mathrm{eq}$, wherein $K_\mathrm{eq} = 1$

What confuses me is the term "unlikely", which I take to mean that it is uncommon yet possible.   Can you explain why having equal concentrations of products and reactants at equilibrium such that $K_\mathrm{eq} = 1$ is both possible yet uncommon?

Comment: Can you give some more context? In what context did your book mention that statement? And equilibrium does not mean there is equal concentration of product and reactant, there are many reactions like $\ce{2A +C ->B} where that isn't true. (If someone is very pedantic then yes, technically perfect equilibrium is impossible to achieve)

Comment: The book said it was an ideal situation for Keq, wherein Keq = 1

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti I assumed this meant ideal equilibrium

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57075/is-there-no-actual-equilibrium/57135#57135

Comment: When you specifically want a value, everything is unlikely. While the thread contains right comments and answers, it is hard to understand the meaning of ideal in the context "to the fact that it was an ideal situation....". One can place 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For a chemical reaction,

$$\Delta G = -R T \ln K_{eq}$$
$$\implies  K_{eq} = e^{\frac{-\Delta G}{RT}} $$

Thus, in order for a chemical reaction to have $K_{eq}=1$*, it is necessary to have $\Delta G = 0$

For some chemical reactions**, we can achieve this by adjusting the temperature and/or pressure. Thus it is possible. However, it's unlikely that the temperature and pressure at which a chemical reaction is taking place is coincidentally just that needed to achieve $\Delta G = 0$.

On the other hand, in finding phase transition temperatures (melting and boiling points), we are sweeping through a range of temperatures specifically to find the points at which the phases coexist, i.e., where their free energies are the same and thus where $\Delta G = 0$.  Thus these *are* equilibria for which $K_{eq}=1$.

*We can never *exactly* get $\Delta G = 0$, because we can never *exactly* adjust T and p; consequently, we can never *exactly* have $K_{eq}=1$.   Thus what I mean (and presumably what your textbook means) when it says "$K_{eq}=1$" is that it is so close to $1$ that it's within the size of the fluctuations about equilibrium.

**I say "for some chemical reactions" because in some cases the reactants or products might break down before the required temperature is reached.   E.g., suppose you were trying to find a reaction involving glucose at which $K_{eq} =1$, and did a theoretical extrapolation in which you found that this occurred at, say, 10,000 K.  Well, glucose doesn't exist at that temperature.

Note #1:  $\Delta G = -R T \ln K_{eq}$ applies to processes carred out at constant T and p. If the process were instead at, say, constant T and V, then the equilibrium condition would be $\Delta A = -R T \ln K_{eq}$.  [And don't be confused: Constant T and p doesn't mean a *specific* T and p.  T and p can be whatever you please, so long as the reactants and products can exist at those conditions.  Rather, constant T and p just means that, whatever T and p are, they stay fixed during the reaction.]

Note #2 (on time to attain equilibrium): The above has nothing to do with whether or not you can get to equilbrium, which is addressed in the question linked in Ivan's comment on your post. That question pertains to any equilibrium, regardless of the value of the equilibrium constant (whether it's 1 or 10.303 or 4.8 x 10^-22, or any other value).  Instead, the above is about whether or not the value of the equilibrium constant can be 1.

Note #3 (on enantiomers in an achiral environment): Andrew raises an interesting point that the reaction:

$$\ce{A_L <=> A_D},$$

where $\ce{A_L}$ and $\ce{A_D}$ are two different enantiomers of compound A, will have $\Delta G = 0$, and thus $K_{eq}=1$, in an achiral environment because, in an achiral environment, the two compounds are chemically identical.  And as they are chemically identical, this will obtain at all temperatures and pressures at which the compound exists.  I.e., in an achiral environment, chemically,

$$\ce{A_L <=> A_D}$$
reduces to:
$$\ce{A <=> A}$$.

But: While enantiomers are chemically identical, the weak nuclear force that exists within their nuclei can recognize handedness, and thus the restriction in the first paragraph still applies:  $K_{eq}$ won't *exactly* equal 1, but can be immeasurably (at least with current technology) close to 1.  [I haven't done the calculation to determine if the difference in energy caused by the weak nuclear force puts the deviation from 1 within the, say, the 90% fluctation range about equilibrium for a representative pair of enantiomers at room temperature.]

Comment: Another example is enantiomers in an achiral environment

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for your comment. See my addition at the end.

Comment: Couldn't the same be said about *any* value of K or $\Delta G^\circ$?? I don't see the point in discussing K=1 as a special case.

Comment: You mean $\Delta G ^\circ = -RT\ln K_{eq}$? (note the superscript indicating std conditions)

Comment: Would you consider an identity reaction, let's say intramolecular proton transfer $$\ce{\color{red}{H}O\color{red}{C}H2\color{blue}{C}H2O\color{blue}{H} <=> \color{blue}{H}O\color{red}{C}H2\color{blue}{C}H2O\color{red}{H}},$$ as still being a valid "reaction"? Apologies for the grotesque colours. This one is a bit contrived, but I think you could still define a rate constant for it, and I'd suspect that there are valid reactions like this which are of genuine interest to someone.

Comment: @orthocresol  I like the colors! Plus they're useful.  I didn't even know you could make those in comments.  Anyways,  I would consider that a trivial case, since nothing is actually changing.   I was also wondering whether the enantiomer reaction in an achiral environment might similarly be considered trivial, but decided in that case that something actually is changing, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @BuckThorn I was thinking about that very issue (should it be $\Delta G^{\circ}$?) yesterday. I explicitly don't want to use that notation, because it restricts us to standard pressure and (for gases) ideal gas behavior, while I wanted to allow for variation in pressure, as well as non-ideality. So I was trying to think of what alternative notation I might use, and hadn't yet come up with anything.

Comment: @BuckThorn   As far as this applying to any value of Keq: Well, partly, but achieving Keq = 1 seems somewhat special, because that's when all the reactants and products are thermodynamically "the same".  Ultimately the question of whether it's worth giving special consideration to Keq=1 is pedagogical rather than scientific, so it's a judgement call.   Anyways, that was the idea behind the question, so I was honoring that.   Also: I said  "partly" in the first sentence because Keq=1 also allows us to include phase transitions.

Comment: How about the concentration of a solute in two connected vessels (e.g. via dialysis membrane). At equilibrium, it should be equal (all other things being equal). Again, the equilibrium constant is 1.

Comment: @KarstenTheis Thats's an interesting example. Let's consider an actual dialysis, where the solute is $\ce{Na+}$, and assume it can pass freely through the membrane. I'd expect $K_{eq} \ne 1$, b/c of the Donnan effect, where anionic proteins confined to the blood side will create a charge imbalance such that equal concs. of $\ce{Na+}$ wouldn't have equal activities.  And even for uncharged solutes, the environments are so diff. on the two sides that equal concs. wouldn't give equal activities. If the environments were identical, then $K_{eq} = 1$, but that seems like a trivial result. Thoughts?

Comment: @theorist For the famous transport examples in biology, the equilibrium constant will be differrent from one because of differences in local charge (proton gradient in oxidative phosphorylation) or ionic strength (potassium and sodium in nerve impulse transmission). I wouldn't say when the equilibrium constant is 1 because of some symmetry is not trivial, just like when the reason is that all species are pure solids or liquids. In either case, there is a reason the equilibrium constant is 1 (rather than a coincidence).

Comment: @BuckThorn that is what I think, too. I have commented (unnoticed, it seems) below the question. Sometimes threads are puzzling.